# Qt Example with HexStringValidator fails

Tags: qt, hex, customvalidator

I am using the following code from this example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialbus-can-example.html

```
enum {
    MaxPayload = 8,
    MaxPayloadFd = 64
};

HexStringValidator::HexStringValidator(QObject *parent) :
    QValidator(parent),
    m_maxLength(MaxPayload)
{
}

HexStringValidator::HexStringValidator(QObject *parent, uint maxLength) :
    QValidator(parent),
    m_maxLength(maxLength)
{
}

class HexStringValidator : public QValidator
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit HexStringValidator(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    explicit HexStringValidator(QObject *parent, uint maxLength);

    QValidator::State validate(QString &input, int &pos) const;

    void setMaxLength(int maxLength);

private:
    uint m_maxLength = 0;
};
```

The problem is in this function:
I have a lineedit with this validator and call it with a valid Hex String.

```
ui->lineEditCANCommand->setValidator(new HexStringValidator(this, 4));
ui->lineEditCANCommand->setText("000003e9");

QValidator::State HexStringValidator::validate(QString &input, int &pos) const
{
    const int maxSize = 2 * static_cast<int>(m_maxLength);
    const QChar space = QLatin1Char(' ');
    QString data = input;
    data.remove(space);

    if (data.isEmpty())
        return Intermediate;

    // limit maximum size and forbid trailing spaces
    if ((data.size() > maxSize) || (data.size() == maxSize && input.endsWith(space)))
        return Invalid;

    // check if all input is valid
    const QRegularExpression re(QStringLiteral("^[[:xdigit:]]*$"));
    if (!re.match(data).hasMatch())
        return Invalid;

    // insert a space after every two hex nibbles
    const QRegularExpression insertSpace(QStringLiteral("(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2} )*[[:xdigit:]]{3}"));
    if (insertSpace.match(input).hasMatch()) {
        input.insert(input.size() - 1, space);
        pos = input.size();
    }

    return Acceptable;
}
```

The function is supposed to change this to "00 00 03 e9"

It however runs endless and creates

> `000003e 9`
>
> `000003e  9`
>
> `000003e   9`
>
> `000003e    9`

What is going wrong? Note, this code is from Qt and not mine.

Comment: Did you step through the code with a debugger? The last `if (insertSpace.match(...)) {` seems to me as if it should be a `while` instead and it also seems to evaluate the capture from the regex wrongly.

Comment: Correct. The last if is the problem. int inserts a space always at `size-1`. I assume that this function was written with a different use case in mind. If a user types in a digit it adds the space if necessary. In my case I need to provide a string with spaces. If so it validates it as correct.The problem is the documentation in the code which is different to what it does.

Answer (score -1):

In Qt6 problem should be gone.
There was related to this problem [issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-90783) and two following commits:
[Can example: Fix crash in payload hex editor](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtserialbus/+/334506),
[CAN Example: Properly format payload hex string](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtserialbus/+/335596)
It is possible to test since Qt 6.2.0.

First, I changed `insertSpace` regular expression to `threeDigits`:

```
QStringLiteral("[[:xdigit:]]{3}")
```

and insert space if 3 digits were added sequentially:

```
input.insert(match.capturedEnd() - 1, space);
```

That solves crash problem (infinite recursion).
Then I added auxilliary condition `isEvenHex` and formatter `formatHexData` with `oneDigitAndSpace` and `threeDigits` regular expressions that removes all extra spaces and add space after every two hex nibbles. I call them respectively on `text change` and `sendButton` click:

```
connect(m_ui->payloadEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, frameIdOrPayloadChanged);

connect(m_ui->sendButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]() {
...
m_ui->payloadEdit->setText(formatHexData(data));
...
}
```

Trying to solve your task I added:

```
QValidator::State HexStringValidator::validate(QString &input, int &pos) const
{
    ...        
    QString data = input;

    const QRegularExpression twoSpaces(QStringLiteral("([\\s]{2})"));
    if (twoSpaces.match(data).hasMatch())
        return Invalid;

    data.remove(space);
    ...
```

But there is one problem: if you are editing string in payload editor you may remove digits and two spaces can occure. The validator won't allow you remove characters between spaces. As a compromise I would introduce

```
threeSpaces(QStringLiteral("([\\s]{3})"));
```

validator instead of `twoSpaces`. With that one you may enter two spaces sequentially but still can edit string. I may ask QtSerialBus developers to include that change too.

Comment: And my final solution would be:  

    const QRegularExpression twoSpaces(QStringLiteral("([\\s]{2})"));
    if (twoSpaces.match(input).hasMatch()) {
        const QRegularExpressionMatch match = twoSpaces.match(input);
        input.replace(match.capturedStart(), 2, ' ');
        pos = match.capturedEnd() - 1;
    }  
But without the rest commits this even probably won't work

Comment: That last change was integrated and will fix Qt 6.3.0 Alpha version:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-95801